# Angular 2/4: Accessing resources not from <base href="...">

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

We've got an angular app embedded within a sitecore site. We're getting some issues with pulling down fonts. Our angular app is deployed to "/resources/angular/sales" and we pull in the main scripts with absolute paths, however the fonts we include are coming relative to the path of the `<base href="/">` so the path to the hosting page.

The angular app provides components for the site and is hosted on multiple pages.

If I make the base `/resources/angular/sales` then angular rewrites the URL to that and the site 404s out.

The 2 options I've thought of are:

1. Prevent angular from updating the url. This would be ideal as we don't want it to update it at all, at least not via routing, we had a minor issue with this as angular appended a `/` to the URL, but we've dealt with that.
2. Disable routing completely, we aren't using it in this app.
3. Tell the app the full location for the fonts etc, i.e. to ignore the `base`

Any way to implement one of these options or another solution would be great.

Comment: I've got a similar issue. I'm bundling my angular code into a Java war, it goes into WEB-INF/app for now. The problem is I get 404s when UI tries to load resources such as inline.bundle.js. How can I tell angular to look into WEB-INF/app for resources?

Answer (score 0):

The baseHref attribute is needed for Angular routing, while the deployUrl attribute can be used to retrieve assets. You can easily check the working of both parameters by checking index.html of the built app.

In my case, I had to set both deployUrl and baseHref for the production configuration (you can do that with Angular CLI 6 in angular.json) to make it work.

The baseHref was then prefixed to all relative URLs, so the ones I wanted to opt out had to be made absolute. In my case it was sufficient to put a "/" before the url, so:

- before: call to 'api/users/123'
- after: call to '/api/users/123'